# UINavigationBar Appears Under StatusBar 20 points

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to display an view(ViewController) on window.

```
ViewImagesController *vvViewImagesController=[[ViewImagesController alloc] init  ];
self.vViewImagesController=vvViewImagesController;
[vvViewImagesController release];
UINavigationController *a=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: vViewImagesController];
[self.view addSubview:a.view];
```

but the navigation bar appeared underneath the status bar 20 points.

[image]

Even I use the codes:

```
[a.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
```

to relocate the view, but the result is same.

Welcome any comment

Comment: +1: I have the same issue and was just about to post a question! Thanks for asking - I'll be interested to see some answers. For those who are interested in some more info, (in my case at least) the view containing the `UINavigationBar` (i.e. the `UINavigationController`'s `view` outlet) is the right size, but the `NavigationBar` is offset 20px down from the top of that view. This isn't related to programatically messing with the statusbar either - I don't ever touch it.

Comment: Please give more context: who is `self`, are you loading from a nib?, what's in the nib if so. Perhaps if you post an xcproj, I could help you out. (BTW, you appear to be leaking both VCs, though that wouldn't cause this issue).

Comment: self is rootViewController, it has it-self's outlet view, I add the vViewImagesController.view to this view

Comment: on rootViewController outlet view: statusbar, top bar, bottom bar are all unspecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead

```
ViewImagesController *vvViewImagesController = [[ViewImagesController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *a = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vvViewImagesController];

[self presentModalViewController:a animated:YES];

[vvViewImagesController release];
[a release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do. It's 1 line and it works:

In viewDidLoad in vvViewImagesController:

```
[self.view setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
```

Whoosh!